# How to delete multiple stacks from AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am working on AWS and here there are multiple cloudformations stacks are deployed.
Now I want to delete them at once so that I can repave the env.

But I didn't find any way to do so. I am using following command to see list of stacks.

```
aws cloudformation list-stacks
```

Can someone help, how can I delete all stacks now ?

Comment: Using just the CLI or can you use the SDK? Is this assuming you don't need to paginate the result of list-stacks as it is a paginated request? There's no built-in command, you will have to loop through the result and delete each stack individually essentially.

Answer (score 1):

You can run a short python script to iterate over your stacks.

```python
    import boto3
    
    cf_client = boto3.client('cloudformation', region_name="us-east-1")
    
    for stack in cf_client.describe_stacks()['Stacks']:
        print("deleting {}".format(stack['StackName']))
        cf_client.delete_stack(StackName=stack['StackName'])
```

If you want to handle edge cases like termination protection, failed deletions, and waiters, use this:

```python
 import boto3
 
 cf_client = boto3.client('cloudformation', region_name="us-east-1")
 deletion_waiter = cf_client.get_waiter('stack_delete_complete')
 cloudformation = boto3.resource('cloudformation')
 
 
 stack_list = cf_client.describe_stacks()['Stacks']
 for st in stack_list:
     stack = cloudformation.Stack(st['StackName'])
     cf_client.update_termination_protection(EnableTerminationProtection=False,StackName=stack.stack_name)
     print(stack.stack_name)
     if stack.stack_status == 'DELETE_FAILED':
         retain_resource = stack.stack_status_reason.split('[')[-1].split(']')[0]
         print("deleting {} while retaining {} ".format(stack.stack_name, retain_resource))
         cf_client.delete_stack(StackName=stack.stack_name, RetainResources=[retain_resource])
     else:
         print("deleting {}".format(stack.stack_name))
         cf_client.delete_stack(StackName=stack.stack_name)
     deletion_waiter.wait( StackName=stack.stack_name,WaiterConfig={'Delay': 30,'MaxAttempts': 6})
```

Answer (score 0):

No where is not a packaged solution for this. But if you want create script for it you should delete the stacks from newest to oldest. With the list-staks command you get the creation date for the stack.

If you want to clear the account you can use tools like:
https://github.com/rebuy-de/aws-nuke